# Plot ctree using rpart.plot functionality

Tags: r, rpart, party

Been trying to use the `rpart.plot` package to plot a `ctree` from the `partykit` library. The reason for this being that the default plot method is terrible when the tree is deep. In my case, my `max_depth = 5`.

I really enjoy `rpart.plot`'s output as it allows for deep trees to visually display better. How the output looks for a simple example:

## rpart

```
library(partykit)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

df_test <- cu.summary[complete.cases(cu.summary),]

multi.class.model <- rpart(Reliability~., data = df_test)

rpart.plot(multi.class.model)
```

[image]

I would like to get this output from the partykit model using ctree

## ctree

```
multi.class.model <- ctree(Reliability~., data = df_test)

rpart.plot(multi.class.model)
>Error: the object passed to prp is not an rpart object
```

Is there some way one could coerce the ctree object to `rpart` so this would run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge all the other packages for visualizing `rpart` trees are really `rpart`-specific and not based on the agnostic `party` class for representing trees/recursive partitions. Also, we haven't tried to implement an `as.rpart()` method for `party` objects because the `rpart` class is really not well-suited for this.

But you can try to tweak the `partykit` visualizations which are customizable through panel functions for almost all aspects of the tree. One thing that might be helpful is to compute a `simpleparty` object which has all sorts of simple summary information in the `$info` of each node. This can then be used in the `node_terminal()` panel function for printing information in the tree display. Consider the following simple example for predicting one of three school types in the German Socio-Economic Panel. To achieve the desired depth I switch significance testing essentiall off:

```
library("partykit")
data("GSOEP9402", package = "AER")
ct <- ctree(school ~ ., data = GSOEP9402, maxdepth = 5, alpha = 0.5)
```

The default `plot(ct)` on a sufficiently big device gives you:

[image: ctree-default]

When turning the tree into a `simpleparty` you get a textual summary by default:

```
st <- as.simpleparty(ct)
plot(st)
```

[image: simpleparty]

This has still overlapping labels so we could set up a small convenience function that extracts the interesting bits from the `$info` of each node and puts them into a longer character vector with less wide entries:

```
myfun <- function(i) c(
  as.character(i$prediction),
  paste("n =", i$n),
  format(round(i$distribution/i$n, digits = 3), nsmall = 3)
)
plot(st, tp_args = list(FUN = myfun), ep_args = list(justmin = 20))
```

[image: simpleparty2]

In addition to the arguments of the terminal panel function (`tp_args`) I have tweaked the arguments of the edge panel function (`ep_args`) to avoid some of the overplotting in the edges.

Of course, you could also change the entire panel function and roll your own...

Comment: thanks @achim-zeileis, appreciate you taking the time to help. Ill play around with the function. What is the official git repo for project, then if I integrate some color schemes to decision nodes and leaves Ill pull request the function

Comment: I would recommend that you start out from `node_terminal` (note that this has the class `grapcon_generator`) and create your own `node_prp_like` (or something like that). The package is not on GitHub but on R-Forge (old-style svn): https://R-Forge.R-project.org/projects/partykit/ Please send suggestions simply via e-mail and then we'll take it from there. If you have further questions, please feel free to ask here, on R-Forge or directly via e-mail if you feel it is too specific for a public forum.