# how to modify terminal node in ctree,plot in R

Tags: r, party, ctree

I'd like to achieve picture like this,
[image]

The following is what I have now:
[image]

How can I modify the code to acquire the picture? I mean，how to remove the $err and $distribution in terminal nodes?
I have read the Rdocumentation for party-plot but in vain.
Thanks in advance.

```
library(openxlsx)
library('partykit')
data<- read.xlsx("2005.XLSX", sheet = 1)
tree<-ctree(inc_total~.,data=data,control = ctree_control(maxdepth = 5))
plot(tree,type='simple',inner_panel=node_inner(tree,id=FALSE),
     terminal_panel = node_terminal(tree,digits=1,id=FALSE,fill=c('white','white'),width = 14,gp=gpar(fontsize=5)))
mean((data$inc_total-predict(tree))^2)
```

Comment: You can use the `FUN` argument of the terminal panel function to customize the text that is shown. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322213/plot-ctree-using-rpart-plot-functionality/48340513#48340513 for a worked and reproducible example.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thank you.I succeed in modifyting the terminal panel. I'm sorry but I have a small question ,the left edges shown in my picture is & but I want $\leq$ ,is it a bug?

Comment: If you provide a minimal reproducible example, I can have a look.